# What happened to the Future Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In [The Flash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288/), the Flash from the future traveled back in time to stop the Reverse-Flash from killing his mother. He failed, but where did he go? The Reverse-Flash was stuck in past, so he killed and took the appearance of Doctor Harrison Wells. In his hidden room we see holograms of newspapers from the year 2024 with article about the Flash gone missing. So he didn't travel back to the future. Where is the future Flash?

Comment: I'm not sure how much time has passed between the Future Flash's disappearance and the writing of the future article, maybe it was written the day of his disappearance? Perhaps he goes missing for a day or two or more upon his return to the future. Good question though.

Comment: This question isn't answerable right now.  There hasn't been any indication on the show or from the writers as to what time period that future Flash came from or where and when he went after he left.

Comment: @Dpeif the article shows that Chief West had the press conference the next morning.

Comment: `The Flash from the future did travel back in time to stop The Reverse-Flash from killing his mother.` Nope, Future Flash went back in time chasing Younger Reverse Flash (the 2024 event), to stop him from killing pre-teen barry. AND as seen in the "Fast Enough", Future Flash explicitly tells Present day Flash ***NOT*** to save Nora.

Comment: And most likely, 2024 Barry got sent to the future, 2100-2500 like he did in the comics.

Comment: Ah, of course.. My mistake about the mother, don't know why i write that. But why would Future Flash (2024) go to 2100-2500? I haven't read comics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't know. 2 seasons in, they haven't brought it up**.

We don't know the extent of Eobard Thawne's supercomputer Gideon's ability to scan the timelines.

We do know is that while the Reverse-Flash is faster than the Flash most of the time, the Flash does not have his issues with time travel. Eobard, in the multiple times we see him time-travel regardless of how, seems to loose his connection to the Speed-Force. Flash, the multiple times we see him time-travel, can do it without any loss of powers.

And due to the constant inconsistencies in how the show handles time-travel (See [Why wasn't the timeline affected any further from the events in the season 1 finale?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42355/)) we don't really know how the show attempts to handle it.

We do know that comic Barry Allen, prior to the DC Crisis of Infinite Earths, during the "Trial of the Flash" in the 80's, essentially leaves the current time and ends up living in the 30th Century, with a reincarnated Iris.

So possibly, after saving his 10 year old self, Future Barry gets sent forward significantly into the future to the 25th or 30th century, Or he returns in 2024 and Gideon simply doesn't know.

Since we only have Eobard's word that he created the particle accelerator explosion 15 years earlier then it normally happened, turning Barry into the Flash much earlier, or if any of the events that shaped Barry into the future Barry that disappeared in 2024, ***we don't know if that timeline exists as that Barry knew it***. The future Flash could be a **Timeline Remnant** of some sort that disappeared.

Comment: Well, okay, i'll accept that, but i guess it doesn't matter anymore. It's 2nd season almost over and what they have done so far with time travel is a complete nonsense, making it even worse with each episode. Since Legends of Tomorrow it has gone off the rails.

Comment: @Lettmannen True, but that is very much how it happens in the comics as well. Speedsters zoom around all over the timelines. Trying to give it any form of consistent logic or finding a pattern of causality and cause and effect is - imho - not even worth a try.

Answer (score -2):

The future flash is, well, in the future. The last episode where Thawne (both of them died) was a major game-changer. If Reverse Flash(Eobard Thawne) was never born, then he never traveled back in time to kill Barry's Mother. This have the same effect as Barry rescuing his mother and everything would change(he would have never met Iris and so on). I am assuming that the future Flash would come back to the past to kill his mother or to let that happen because the older flash stopped the younger Flash from rescuing his mother. Sry if it was a little off topic- i think he disappeared because he went back to stop his younger self.

Comment: Why would Barry never have met Iris? They were already best friends (Joe says so to a fellow cop while processing Nora's crime scene: Unknown Cop: "Do you know these people". Joe: "Their kid is best friends with my daughter". (or "My daughter is best friends with their kid", can't recall which way right now, but no matter, the meaning is the same.) We know Reverse Flash still exists, despite never having been born, because some (Timeline Remnant) version of him still has to kill Nora, who after all is still very much dead [which is why Barry had to help the earlier version get back home].